# spamassassin "spamd child" process using 90% or more CPU

Tags: process, cpu-load, spamassassin

On my Ubuntu box, one of `spamd child` processes often takes 90%+ CPU.

- This started a few months ago. The box had worked for many years without this problem.
- I thought installing 21.10 caused it and installing 22.04 would fix it, but 22.04 did not fix it.

Here's sample output from `strace`:

```
pread64(10, "\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0dG\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0.\1\334\10\0\r\372\17\364\17\356\17"..., 4096, 74858496) = 4096
pread64(10, "\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0eG\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0D\1(\10\0\r\372\17\364\17\356\17"..., 4096, 74862592) = 4096
pread64(10, "\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0fG\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0>\1l\10\0\r\372\17\364\17\356\17"..., 4096, 74866688) = 4096
pread64(10, "\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0gG\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0&\1\34\t\0\r\372\17\364\17\356\17"..., 4096, 74870784) = 4096
pread64(10, "\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0hG\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0>\1l\10\0\r\372\17\364\17\356\17"..., 4096, 74874880) = 4096
pread64(10, "\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0iG\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0<\1p\10\0\r\372\17\364\17\356\17"..., 4096, 74878976) = 4096
pread64(10, "\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0jG\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\374\0\370\t\0\r\372\17\364\17\356\17"..., 4096, 74883072) = 4096
```

Other things I have tried (that didn't work):

- sa-learn --clear
- deleting the many `bayes_toks.expire*` files in `/home/vmail/.spamassassin/`
- restarting `spamassassin` will reduce the CPU load temporarily, but it will return.

Comment: Hiya, have you read [this post](https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/spamd-child.29873/) on the cpanel forums? Old, but the solution listed near the bottom (the one suggesting editing a line in `/etc/rc.d/init.d/exim`) may still be relevant.

Comment: I'm using postfix, not exim, so that won't work for me. I checked max-children, and it's 5. The number of child processes does not appear to be the problem.